# How to open a file which has name with unicode symbols

Tags: c++, qt, unicode

I created an .exe file and associated .myFile extension to that .exe file. I want to double click on any .myFile file and get that file opened by the .exe. For that I have done the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString fileName(QObject::tr(argv[1]));
    if ( fileName != "" )
    {
        mainWin.loadFile(fileName);
    }
.................. 
}
```

But when I have named my file in unicode characters (e.g. "Здравствуй.myFile"), the instead of "Здравствуй" you can see "????????". How to solve this problem? I know this is solved problem because, for example, MS Word does that.

Comment: OT. But QObject::tr() is for translation of UI text. Unless you mean to open the file with translated name, you shouldn't use tr() here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The previous answers that focus on `int main(int argc, char** argv)` are needlessly complex. Qt has a better alternative.

From the Qt documentation: [On Windows, the `QApplication::arguments()` are not built from the contents of argv/argc, as the content does not support Unicode. Instead, the arguments() are constructed from the return value of GetCommandLine().](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qcoreapplication.html#arguments)

So, the correct answer is to use `qApp.arguments().at(1)`, which will give you the Unicode filename in a QString.

Comment: And what argument I should pass to QApplication constructor in order to be able to call the function mentioned by you then.

Comment: What is qApp? Where i construct or get it?

Comment: See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qapplication.html#qApp : All Qt apps should have that macro. You should pass the normal argc/argv from main. They're ignored on Windows, but it keeps your program portable to Mac and Linux

Comment: OK, ok!! I got in, it is just the old budddy QApplication app(argc, argv);  I didn't know that windows ignores that, thus it was strange. What about mac and linux, how they handle this situation do they ignore too?

Comment: On modern Unix-like systems, `char*` strings are usually UTF-8, which can be easily converted to Qt's UTF-16 strings.

Comment: Again, see the first link in my answer. Continue to pass the arguments from `int main(int argc, char** argv)` to the QApplication constructor. On Mac and Linux, those will usually be UTF-8, and Qt will call `QString::fromLocal8Bit()` to do the UTF-8 to Qstring conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `wmain` instead of `main` on Windows:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t** argv) {
    QString fileName = QString::fromWCharArray(argv[1]);  // untested
```

If you have to follow the C standard (which is all but useless on Windows), you can use `GetCommandLineW` and `CommandLineToArgvW` instead.

Comment: If you say how to convert  wchar_t** argv into  char** argvCHAR then I can pass in to QApplication constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the unicode you pass in is actually stored as UTF-8, try using QString::fromUtf8 to read the argument, something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString fileName(QObject::trUtf8(argv[1]));
    if ( fileName != "" )
    {
        mainWin.loadFile(fileName);
    }
    // stuff
}
```

QObject::trUtf8 is actually a wrapper that will utilize QString:fromUtf8 and still perform the translation (even though i dont understand why you want to translate file names)

Comment: It is not stored as UTF-8 on Windows.